# Strange replace on magento URL

Tags: magento

For some reason, only on view-mode icons on the product list, the "?" of the urls are replaced to "#21". Ex.: `"#%21mode=list"`

Somebody can help me?

Some code:

app/design/frontend/default/themename/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

```
<?php if( $this->isEnabledViewSwitcher() ): ?>
<p class="view-mode">
    <?php $_modes = $this->getModes(); ?>
    <?php if($_modes && count($_modes)>1): ?>
    <label><?php echo $this->__('View as') ?>:</label>
    <?php foreach ($this->getModes() as $_code=>$_label): ?>
        <?php if($this->isModeActive($_code)): ?>
            <strong title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?>"><?php echo $_label ?></strong>&nbsp;
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getModeUrl($_code) ?>" title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?>"><?php echo $_label ?></a>&nbsp;
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

app/code//core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

```
public function getModeUrl($mode)
{
    return $this->getPagerUrl( array($this->getModeVarName()=>$mode, $this->getPageVarName() => null) );
}
```

and...

```
public function getPagerUrl($params=array())
{
    $urlParams = array();
    $urlParams['_current']  = true;
    $urlParams['_escape']   = true; // I already tried set false, but didn't helps
    $urlParams['_use_rewrite']   = true;
    $urlParams['_query']    = $params;
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/*', $urlParams); // I also tried not use the getUrl and concat the querystring, strangely the replace still happends...
}
```

Comment: Try searching your files for '#%21' and see what you find.

Comment: This is likely the result of URL encoding, but it needs more detail. When exactly does this happen? Can you show the code that creates those icons?

Comment: of course! I added some code up there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the problem, but I make a dirt solution:

`<?php echo str_replace('#%21', '&', $this->getModeUrl($_code)); ?>`

I wish somebody find a better solution :)